# How to use loadie.js for displaying individual progress bars for loading multiple images?

Tags: jquery

I had a simple requirement to show individual progress bars on top of multiple images whilst they were loading (in a page, not when being uploaded in a form).

I searched for image preloading and loading plugins but couldn't find anything that matched the simple visual design and implementation effort I was after.

So I've used [loadie.js](http://9elements.github.io/loadie.js) perhaps in a way it wasn't originally intended to display progress bars for multiple images.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/XeX2n/15/

How to make each instance of `loadie` unique to each image, so that the `on("load", function()` function I am using to mark each image as loaded is unique to each image?

**HTML**

```
<div class="image_container">
<div class="my_loadie_container"></div>
<div class="img_cover"></div>
<img class="my_image" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/">
</div>
<div class="image_container">
<div class="my_loadie_container"></div>
<div class="img_cover"></div>
<img class="my_image" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/transport/">
</div>
<div class="image_container">
<div class="my_loadie_container"></div>
<div class="img_cover"></div>
<img class="my_image" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/technics/">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image_container {
width:55px;   
position:relative;
}

/* needed so that loadie is centered and 
   not the full width of the thumbnail when fully loaded  */  
.my_loadie_container {
position:absolute !important; 
height:15px;
width:42px; 
left:7px;   
z-index:9999;
}

.img_cover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inline-block;
height: 50px;
left: 2px;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
width: 55px;
}

.my_image {
width:55px;
height:50px;
border-radius:5px;
border:2px solid #333333;
}

.loadie {
position: absolute;
top:19px;
left:0px;
background-color: #fff;
width: 0;
height: 15px;
border-radius:2px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.my_loadie_container').loadie(); 

// add a bit more progress
var progress = 0.2
setTimeout(function() {
$('.my_loadie_container').loadie(progress);
}, 300);

// add a bit more progress
var progress = 0.4
setTimeout(function() {
$('.my_loadie_container').loadie(progress);
}, 100);

// add a bit more progress
var progress = 0.6
setTimeout(function() {
$('.my_loadie_container').loadie(progress);
}, 200);

// set progress to 100%
$(".my_image").on ("load",function() {
//alert('I loaded!');
percent = 1;
$('.my_loadie_container').loadie(percent);
$(".img_cover").fadeOut();
}).attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/');
```

**Edit:** Updated to use `on("load", function()` instead of `load()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It may have less than ideal code, but it's working.  If anyone wants to fix the bad bits feel free.  I made some adjustments so that all the classes were dynamic so that it will scale no matter how many images are on the page.

*Bad Bits*

I'm new to Javascript, but from reading some best practises, these are *some* of the 'bad bits'.

- Uses `eval()`.
- Has selectors in a loop.

But for this newb it is somewhat satisfying to get it working at least.

**jsFiddle**

*updated version* - http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/XeX2n/29/

**jQuery**

```
// there are 2 functions:
// 
// 01.  prepareImageLoading()
// 02:  removeImageLoading()
// 

// 02. remove the preparations

function removeImageLoading() {
cl_counter = 1;
$('.my_loadie_container').each(function(i, obj) {
console.log("removing loadie container class: " + cl_counter);
$(this).removeClass('my_loadie_container_' + cl_counter++);
});

img_cl_counter = 1;
$('.my_image').each(function(i, obj) {
console.log("removing image class: " + img_cl_counter);
$(this).removeClass('my_image_' + img_cl_counter++);
$(this).unbind();
});

var $loadie_container_1 = undefined;
var $loadie_container_2 = undefined;
var $loadie_container_3 = undefined;

$(".loadie").remove();

var my_object_array = [];

console.log("unset loadie containers, remove loadie divs and unbind classes attached to load");
}

// 01.  prepare the environment

function prepareImageLoading() {

// dyanmically add unique loadie container to each
// div called my_loadie_container

cl_counter = 1;
$('.my_loadie_container').each(function(i, obj) {
$(this).addClass('my_loadie_container_' + cl_counter++);
});

// dynamically add unique class to all images
// with .my_image class

img_cl_counter = 1;
$('.my_image').each(function(i, obj) {
$(this).addClass('my_image_' + img_cl_counter++);
});

// create an array of objects 
// containing properties of the images

var my_object_array = [];
var loadie_counter = 1;
var $img_properties_array = $(".image_container img").map(function() {
var img_src = $(this).attr("src");
var img_class = $(this).attr("class");
my_object = {};
my_object.img_src = img_src;
my_object.img_class = img_class;
my_object.loadie_instance = "$loadie_container_" + loadie_counter++;
my_object_array.push(my_object);
});

// check access to properties
$.each(my_object_array, function (obj,v) {
console.log('image source: ' + v.img_src);
console.log('image class: ' + v.img_class);
});

// define loadie instances
// (this should be made dynamic to scale to number
// of required instances)
var $loadie_container_1 = $('.my_loadie_container_1');
var $loadie_container_2 = $('.my_loadie_container_2');
var $loadie_container_3 = $('.my_loadie_container_3');

// for each loadie instance, add some progress
$.each(my_object_array, function (obj,v) {
setTimeout(function() {
var progress = 0.2;
eval(v.loadie_instance).loadie(progress);
}, 300);
});

// for each image, set progress to 1 when
// image has finished loading
var counter = 1;
var new_counter = 0;
var d = new $.Deferred();
$.each(my_object_array, function (obj,v) {
counter = counter++;
var img_class = v.img_class;
// just get the dynamically added img class
var img_class_array = img_class.split(" ");
var img_class = img_class_array[img_class_array.length - 1];
// check access to img_class
console.log('img_class: ' + img_class);
var class_constructor = "." + img_class;
// check the class_constructor
console.log('class_constructor: ' + class_constructor);
// when each image has finished loading
// set loadie progress to 1
$(class_constructor).on ("load",function() {
var progress = 1;
var loadie_constructor = "$loadie_container_" + counter++;
// check the loadie_constructor
console.log('loadie_constructor: ' + loadie_constructor);
eval(loadie_constructor).loadie(progress);
$(".img_cover:eq(" + eval(new_counter++) + ")").fadeOut(1000);
if (new_counter == my_object_array.length) {
console.log("object array length: " + my_object_array.length);
setTimeout(function() {
d.resolve();
}, 1000);
};
});
// for some reason this only gets to 1
console.log('counter: ' + counter);
});
return d.promise(); 
}

// 03.  the calls
prepareImageLoading();
prepareImageLoading().done(removeImageLoading);
```